# I want to add a prompt in the beginning of my script asking if it is a local device(the one the user is on) or network, and after picking it continues

Tags: powershell, scripting

I want to be able to ask the user if it is a local device and if yes then skip the part about asking the computers name and ask what user they want to copy the files from. If no then I want it to ask the computers name and the user then proceed as normal. I can't figure out the local device part in the beginning. After they pick local, I also want the destination to change to a local one as well. I have my code below but it only works if I put the network computer name and user, I first want a local option in case there is no internet connection available. Something like

Is this a local machine?
If Yes ask for the user to copy from and do the rest of the code EXCEPT the destination will be different
If No then ask for the Network machine and then user and proceed with the code below.

```
$FoldersToCopy = @(
    'Desktop'
    'Downloads'
    'Favorites'
    'Documents'
    'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default'
    )

$ConfirmComp = $null
$ConfirmUser = $null
$confirmDelete = $null
$theDate = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy HH;mm"

while( $ConfirmComp -ne 'y' ){
    $Computer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the computer to copy from'

    if( -not ( Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 2 -Quiet ) ){
        Write-Warning "$Computer is not online. Please enter another computer name."
        continue
        }

    $ConfirmComp = Read-Host -Prompt "The entered computer name was:`t$Computer`r`nIs this correct? (y/n)"
    }

while( $ConfirmUser -ne 'y' ){
    $User = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the user profile to copy from'

    if( -not ( Test-Path -Path "\\$Computer\c$\Users\$User" -PathType Container ) ){
        Write-Warning "$User could not be found on $Computer. Please enter another user profile."
        continue
        }

    $ConfirmUser = Read-Host -Prompt "The entered user profile was:`t$User`r`nIs this correct? (y/n)"
    }

$SourceRoot      = "\\$Computer\c$\Users\$User"
$DestinationRoot = "\\personal\users\$User\backups\$theDate"
$checkThis = "\\personal\users\$User\backups\$theDate"

if (Test-Path $checkThis) {
   
    Write-Host "Folder Exists"
    while( $confirmDelete -ne 'y' ){
    $checking = Read-Host -Prompt 'Do you want to erase current data and replace with the new? (y/n)'
    $confirmDelete = Read-Host -Prompt "Are you sure you want to delete? (y/n)"

    Remove-Item $checkThis -Force

    New-Item $checkThis -ItemType Directory
    Write-Host "Folder Created successfully"
    }
    
}
else
{
  
    #PowerShell Create directory if does not exists
    New-Item $checkThis -ItemType Directory
    Write-Host "Folder Created successfully"
}

foreach( $Folder in $FoldersToCopy ){
    $Source      = Join-Path -Path $SourceRoot -ChildPath $Folder
    $Destination = Join-Path -Path $DestinationRoot -ChildPath $Folder

    if( -not ( Test-Path -Path $Source -PathType Container ) ){
        Write-Warning "Could not find path`t$Source"
        continue
        }

    Robocopy.exe $Source $Destination /E /IS /NP /NFL /B
    }
    Write-Host "PowerShell Done, Have a great day!"
```

Comment: So where are you having trouble implementing what you just suggested? Seems pretty straight forward

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I am awful at powershell and I googled my way through this and now I am stuck